# Expose Map in private guice module

Tags: java, guice

I have a PrivateModule in guice and I want to expose a Map from that module

```
public class TestInjectionModule extends PrivateModule {
expose(Map.class).annoatedWith(Names.named("map"));
}
```

provider for the map

```
@Named("map")
@Provides
@Singleton
Map<String, String> providesMap(@Named("name1") String v1, @Named("name2") String v2){
 return ImmutableMap.of("key1", v1, "key2", v2);
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Could not expose() java.util.Map annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=map), it must be explicitly bound.
```

what is the correct way to expose this map?

Answer (score 0):

Does this even compile?

`expose(Map.class).annotatedWith("map");`

As per Javadoc, [`annotatedWith`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/binder/AnnotatedElementBuilder.html) takes an Annotation, not a String.

Try this:

`expose(Map.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("map"));`

[`Names.named()`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/name/Names.html) javadoc

Also, make sure to add a `@Provides` annotation to your provider method

Comment: add `@Provides` annotation to your provider method