# Expose Map from guice private Module

Tags: java, guice, inject

I am trying to expose a map from private module similar to [Expose Map in private guice module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58036280/expose-map-in-private-guice-module) but getting an error

Could not expose() java.util.Map annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=myMap), it must be explicitly bound.

I have written this code:

```
expose(Map.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(myMap));

@Named("myMap")
@Provides
@Singleton
public Map<String, String> myMap() {
    // myMap
    return ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
            .build();
}
```

Also in another class where I am injecting it, it gives:

No implementation for java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> was bound.

Please check. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To this Guice offers [multibinders](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings) and, in particular, for your case, [MapBinder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) which in its Javadoc provides a nice code example.